# How to print the three rows with the highest values in a single column in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pd.dataframe that look like this:

```
    0   1
0   10  0.9679487179487178
1   38  0.9692307692307693
2   24  0.9833333333333332
3   62  0.9525641025641025
4   17  0.9679487179487178
5   23  0.9679487179487178
6   72  0.9679487179487178
7   22  0.9538461538461538
8   90  0.9525641025641025
9   32  0.9666666666666668
```

How can I ask python to print out something like this:
"Highest accuracy was 0.9833333333333332 using 24 features, second highest accuracy
was 0.9692307692307693 with 38 features, third highest accuracy was at 0.9679487179487178
with 10 features"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you sort your dataframe by that accuracy like so:

```
df.sort_values(by=["1"], inplace=True)
```

And you want the three highest accuracies you can do:

```
for i in range(3):
   print(f"Top {i+1} accuracy was {df["1"].loc[i]} with {df["0"].loc[i]} features")
```

If you want to print exactly what you wrote on the question then just replace `{i+1}` with `{order[i]}` and create `order = ["Highest", "Second Highest", "Third Highest"]`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`pandas.DataFrame.nlargest`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nlargest.html)

```py
out = df.nlargest(3, '1')
```

```
print(out)

    0         1
2  24  0.983333
1  38  0.969231
0  10  0.967949
```

Answer (score 1):

Sort the file with the acc column something like this:

```
data.sort_values("column name", axis=0, ascending=True, inplace=True, na_position='first')
```

and then print what you want in order